# How do you use a button click function to convert an PHAsset to a UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, swift2, phasset

Ok, so i've been at this for a while and I just can't seem to solve it.

I have an ImagePicker which bundles images into PHAssest. It's from https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker

When an image is selected, the done button is activated. I have a UIImageView which when i press the `func doneButtonDidPress(images: [UIImage])`, would convert the PHAsset into a UIImage and load it into the ImageView. Currently, this is my code which doesn't work:

```
// CONVERT PHASSET TO UIIMAGE
func getAsset(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
var image = UIImage()
option.synchronous = true
manager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0), contentMode: .AspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
    image = result!
})
return image
}




func doneButtonDidPress(images: [UIImage]) {



self.imagePickerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
var selectedImg = imagePickerController.stack.assets

getAsset(selectedImg)
self.SelectedImageView.image = UIImage(named: selectedImg)



}
```

Which flags with errors. Can anyone help me here?! Thankyou

Comment: I don't see in your code where you get the return UIImage from the function `getAsset()` , and what is `chosenImg` ? 
I would have do this : 
`self.SelectImageView.image = getAsset(selectedImg)`

Comment: the  `func getAsset(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage` has been returned right before it's last curly brackets as `return image`. PS: Ignore the chosenImg. I I have updated it. If by any chance you can re-write the function all in one button instead of calling it in the button, that would be awesome. However, any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting `UIImage` from `PHAsset` like :

```
func getAsset(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
var image = UIImage()
let imgManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
            let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
            requestOptions.synchronous = true
            imgManager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSizeMake(300.0, 300.0), contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (img, _) in
                image = img
            })
return image
}
```

This code is tested & currently working in my application.

Done Button method should be like :

```
func doneButtonDidPress(image: [UIImage]) {
self.imagePickerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
var selectedImg = imagePickerController.stack.assets.first
self.selectedImageView.image = getAsset(selectedImg)
}
```

Comment: the `self.selectedImageView.image = getAsset(selectedImg)` is flagging up with an error value of type UIViewController has no member selectedImageView

Comment: which `UIImageView` you want to add image to ? Can you share complete controller code to check if you have outlet for `selectedImageView` ? Also make sure of the spellings maybe i have misspelled.

Comment: excellent, works perfectly now. Thanks @Muhammad. I just had to change the UIImageView's name.